# Equivalent of Delegate.Target for LambdaExpression

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

Given the following class:

```
public class Foo {
    public string Bar {get; set;}
    Func<string> GetFunc = () => Bar;
}
```

the following code will print `True`:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var fn = foo.GetFunc;
Console.WriteLine(fn.Target == foo);
```

because the target of the `action` delegate is the instance of the object.

**How can I get a hold of an expression that represents the target of a `LambdaExpression` returned by an instance?**

```
public class Foo1 {
    public string Bar {get;set;}
    Expression<Func<string>> GetExpression = () => Bar;
}

var foo = new Foo();
var expr = foo.GetExpression;
// ???
```

I thought compiling `expr` and checking the `Target` property of the generated delegate would work, and it does return an instance of [Closure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.closure), where `foo` is one of the objects referred to by the array at the [Constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.closure.constants) property.

```
var closure = expr.Compile().Target as System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure;
Console.WriteLine(closure.Constants.Contains(foo));
// prints True
```

However, this doesn't help me, because if I construct the expression using the factory methods at [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression), and specify an external instance as a `Constant` within the expression tree:

```
// using static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression;

var foo = new Foo();
Expression<Func<string>> expr = Lambda<Func<string>>(
    MakeMemberAccess(
        Constant(foo),
        typeof(Foo).GetMember("Bar").Single()
    )
);
```

the external instance (`foo` in this case) will also be included in the `Constants`.

I am looking specifically for the object (or objects) referred to by `this` in a compiler-generated `LambdaExpression` (and if there are no conflicts with other identifiers, the `this` can be elided).

(Some background can be found [here](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeToString/issues/30).)

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to do? For me your question sounds like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). `Expression<Func<string>>` can be compiled to static method, so `Target` should be `null`

Comment: @AleksAndreev Do you mean by calling `CompileToMethod` (which returns a method definition)? Presumably that could return a static method, but I've never used `CompileToMethod`, so I don't know. But if we're talking about calling `Compile` and returning a delegate instance, that delegate instance  will **never** be static; delegate instances which wrap static methods have `null` in their `Target` property. Instead, the `Target` is always an instance of [Closure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.closure), with an empty array at the `Constants` property.

Comment: @AleksAndreev My ultimate problem is: when calling an instance member within an expression inside of a class, the compiler wraps the instance of the class in a `ConstantExpression` when generating the expression. How can I differentiate between a `ConstantExpression` created this way, from a `ConstantExpression` constructed using the `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant` factory method? Because when rendering the expression as a string, the 1st can be written `Bar` or `this.Bar`; the 2nd needs to show the instance of the member (which I usually represent as `#Foo`), e.g. `#Foo.Bar`.